# csc.exe call fails during runtime

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, jit, csc

When running my C# application i randomly get the following error (currently only on WindowsXP, not reproduceable by us - only at one customer machine)...

> Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\TSBenutzer\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp\r2ng5zrw.cmdline".

It looks like it only happens in use cases that try to load objects from the MySQL Database. During those database calls DLLs are used which already have been loaded before, execpt in some cases for autogenerated XMLSerialization classes (we load some objects from XML-text from the database, using XmlSerializer). I read, that those Serialization DLLs are generated during runtime when necessary, could this cause a problem? csc.exe only makes sense for me in terms of JIT compilation.

All other posts i found on the internet had to do with technology-specific issues like report generation or webservers.

Comment: If you can, set a breakpoint when that error happens. Then look in that directory what is being executed. It looks like a temp source file is failing to compile.

Comment: This is all entirely normal.  Yes, XML serialization uses System.CodeDom to auto-generate the serialization assembly if it can't find a pre-cooked one made with sgen.exe.  Csc.exe is the C# compiler.  The customer needs to fix the machine.  Fix any disk damage, preferably by replacing the disk drive, and reinstall .NET 4.0.  Not your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations - i will tell the customer to fix the disk and reinstall .NET
@leppie: I won't be able to set a breakpoint, because the machine is at the customer's office and there is no comfortable possibility to start a debug session. I will try to let him fix the installation and see if further steps are necessary - thanks alot!